# Using the bytes of an NSMutableData instance while allowing it to be autoreleased

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, nsmutabledata

I've been using

```
NSMutableData* mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: someLength];
void* bitmapData = [mutableData mutableBytes];
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData,...);
// ...use context
CGContextRelease(context);
```

I have an autorelease pool in place, but when looking at this in Instruments, `mutableData` doesn't seem to be deallocated.
I thought of using `alloc`/`init` like below, but I'm not sure if sending `release` would purge `bitmapData` as well.

```
NSMutableData* mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength: someLength];
void* bitmapData = [mutableData mutableBytes];
[mutableData release];
//...
```

What's the proper way of using `NSMutableData` here?

I thought using `NSMutableData` instead of `malloc()` and `free()` would be convenient because it'll be autoreleased. but now I'm not sure if that's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `mutableData` doesn't seem to be deallocated, do you mean at the point of `CGContextRelease()`, or do you mean it never deallocates and it leaks every time you run this?

In your first example, you would not expect `mutableData` to deallocate until the autorelease pool drains (generally at the end of the event loop), because you used `-dataWithLength:`. In your second example, it's undefined whether `mutableData` would be released. The call to `-mutableBytes` might apply a retain and autorelease to ensure the pointer is valid for the rest of the event loop (this is pretty common with these kinds of methods), but the docs don't say, so your second example is undefined behavior if you use `bitmapData` later.

Now if `mutableData` leaks, then you're likely over-retaining it somewhere else.

Comment: yes it never deallocates even after CGContextRelease().. I don't pass the raw data or NSMutableData to anything else than the context create function.

Comment: By "never" you mean, even after the event loop has completed, such that when you call this multiple times your overall memory usage continues to grow?

Comment: grr, had other leaks somewhere else which retains the image created from the context, not sure that retains the raw byte therefore mutabledata as well. But having removed other leaks, instrument doesn't show mutableData as alive.. maybe instruments were confused

Answer (score 0):

Asking an instance of NSMutableData for its mutableBytes simply returns a pointer to the existing (already allocated) buffer that it manages for you. It does not have any effect on the memory from a management perspective.

So, in your first example, the fact that mutableData doesn't appear to be deallocated when looking at it in Instruments could be related to the autorelease pool environment at the time. Does the code using mutableData in that way have an NSAutoreleasePool in place? Do you see warnings in the console like "autorelease called with no pool in place; just leaking"? If so, you just need to wrap the code in:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// bitmap drawing code here
[pool drain];
```

In the second sample, you could use alloc/init on the NSMutableData instance, but you would need to release it after you were done using the pointer you get from mutableBytes. The pointer will be pointing to deallocated (freed) memory after you call release, and accessing it will result in the dreaded EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Also, using malloc/free would probably be my first choice here, since you get to be very explicit about how and when the memory is allocated and freed. NSMutableData + autorelease isn't really buying you anything except some overhead, if you aren't using the object for anything else.